# What is the shape of the vibration when the system is exited at off natural/resonant frequency?

Tags: vibrations, normal-modes

I understand that when the system is exited and left to vibrate freely many of its vibrational modes will be present as a linear combination. If the system undergoes a forced vibration at one of the natural frequency of the system it would vibrate at with the corresponding shaped associated with that frequency and also with maximum aptitude as allowed by the damping of the system.

But what happens if the frequency of the excitation force is not equal to one of the natural frequency of the system. I have read that system would vibrate at the frequency of excitation will low amplitude. But what would be the shape of vibration?

Comment: That depends on the system. Here is a simulation of a string (needs Java): http://www.falstad.com/loadedstring/  Or this one (html5): https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/wave-on-a-string

Comment: @Pieter Thank you for the app. I have tried using it and if I understand correctly, in this app the available frequencies excitation force is little above the fundamental frequency not reaching the second harmonic frequency. Also, I have observed that when the excitation frequency is between fundamental frequency and second harmonic the shape of the deformation is always like that of the first mode(since the force is applied in middle I understand there is no second mode). My question is the is the mode shape only limited to the first mode? or when the frequency of excitation is near to ..

Comment: ..3rd harmonic (ie somewhere between 2n and 3rd harmonic) will the mode shape change? to include the 3rd mode shape?

Comment: About the PhET simulation? There are so many parameters that the total behaviour depends on: termination (spectrum of eigenmodes), tension (frequencies of the eigenmodes), driving frequency, damping. But the eigenmodes themselves always are these sinusoidal standing waves.